When I'm using BitBlt() to capture a screenshot of my explorer, the captured title bar is black and shifted position
I'm trying to capture a window by its HWND, like my explorer:

But this is the result I get:

This is the function I am using:
def capture_window(hwnd):
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_RESTORE)
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
    time.sleep(1)

    window_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    dc_object = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(window_dc)
    compatible_dc = dc_object.CreateCompatibleDC()

    left, top, right, bottom = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)
    width = right - left
    height = bottom - top

    bitmap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc_object, width, height)
    compatible_dc.SelectObject(bitmap)

    compatible_dc.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), dc_object, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    bmpinfo = bitmap.GetInfo()
    bmpstr = bitmap.GetBitmapBits(True)
    img = Image.frombuffer(
        "RGB", (bmpinfo["bmWidth"], bmpinfo["bmHeight"]), bmpstr, "raw", "BGRX", 0, 1
    )

    img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    win32gui.DeleteObject(bitmap.GetHandle())
    compatible_dc.DeleteDC()
    dc_object.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, window_dc)

    return img

The title bar is black, and there is some shift in its position.
Some windows seem alright, but some are not (like explorer). What is causing this?
I tried to fix it with changing win32gui.GetClientRect() to win32gui.GetWindowRect(), but it didn't work.  I am expecting it can capture a same image.

The windows DC does not include the themed elements which are drawn independently. You could get the screen DC then capture the window based on its on screen coordinates - this will fail if the window is clipped or occluded. Also see https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/16/new-ways-to-do-screen-capture/
